# Get Current slide index with Glide.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, swiper.js, glidejs

how can I get the current slide index/number when I swipe between elements with GLide.js

```
 const config = {
    type: "carousel",
    perView: 5,
    startAt: 2,
    perTouch: 1,
    focusAt: "center",
  };
  new Glide(".glide", config)
    .on("swipe.end", function (event) {
      console.log(event);
    })
    .mount();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [`glide.index`](https://glidejs.com/docs/api/#index-small-type-number-small-)

```
const config = {
  type: "carousel",
  perView: 5,
  startAt: 2,
  perTouch: 1,
  focusAt: "center",
};

var glide = new Glide(".glide", config)

glide.on("swipe.end", function(event) {
  console.log('on swipe.end', glide.index)
})

glide.mount()

console.log(glide.index)
```